# Why do people on this site close questions with a message asking for “more research to be shown”?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I asked a very clear question and it got closed!

My reaction to this was “Why are you all so mean and quick to criticize? I just want some help here, not censorship and more work.”

> Actually, my first reaction was anger and hostility to a specific entitled know it all on the internet telling me what to do. Then, I remembered I an expert in this other field and maybe this know it all doesn’t even know what I know. But, I’m glad I didn’t lash out at them cause I’m awesome and those words would have been counterproductive.

One key reason *my question was viewed as suspect* was it had a line just like one of these:

- I googled this and nothing helped.
- I tried everything and none of it worked.
- I could not find anything in google in a reasonable amount of time.
- All the links I found are outdated and I wondered if anything has changed since then.

Please forgive me, that was the best “marketing” I had left in me to dress up my question before posting it. It felt good, but it also marks the point where I stopped analysis and being descriptive of my process to isolate the issue at hand.

Odd thing is, statements like these are both totally true and thoroughly unproductive to describe the sort of help I seek from an audience of thousands.

[I can remove this chit chat with an edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour) but I also need help adding the missing words that “show my research” so that [people with reputation to cast reopen votes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions) do so.

**Are there any example questions that show an edit that adds good research or general guidance on what showing my research looks like?**

Comment: p.s. this question is not about you if you asked or posted recently here. It’s been in draft form for several weeks. Also, I have posted my share of questionable questions in the past and many of them are still out there if you search for them. Thanks to many kind people, some of them are better now with edits and I aim to do so less frequently going forward.